# Analysis of the long division algorithm in the Knuth book (Seminumerical algorithms) 1

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques, arithmetic, mathematical-analysis

I've been reading through the long division algorithm exposed in the Knuth book for a week and I still miss some details. There's an implementation of such algorithm in "Hacker's Delight" by Warren, however basically the author explains that it's a translation of the classic pencil and paper method and the Knuth book is the one that provides all the details. I really want to understand the analysis but for some reason that I can't quite understand it is a bit strange in the exposition.

It firstly starts by saying that

> "a moment's reflection about the ordinary process of long division shows that the general problem breaks down into simpler steps, each of which is the division of an $n+1$-place dividend $u$ by an $n$ place integers $v$.

I of course agree with such intuition, but it's because I've been taught in that way, not because there's a proof. It shouldn't be hard to work out the why however since

$$
\begin{array}{l}
u = \sum_{j=0}^{m+n-1} u_j b^j \\
v = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} v_j b^j
\end{array} \Rightarrow \frac{u}{v} = \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m+n-1} u_j b^j}{v} =
\frac{\sum_{j=m-1}^{m+n-1} u_j b^j}{v} + \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} u_j b^j}{v} = \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{n} u_{j+m-1} b^{j+m-1}}{v} + \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} u_j b^j}{v} =
\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{n} u_{j+m-1} b^j}{v}b^{m-1} + \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} u_j b^j}{v} = \left(q_{m-1} + \frac{r_{m-1}}{v} \right)b^{m-1} + \frac{\sum_{j=0}^{m-2} u_j b^j}{v} = q_{m-1}b^{m-1} + \frac{r_{m-1}b^{m-1} + \sum_{j=0}^{m-2} u_j b^j}{v}
$$
where $0 \leq r_{m-1} \leq v - 1$, using an induction argument I can show that I have always to do this (i.e. that the problem is to perform several iteration of dividing an $n+1$ digit number by an $n$ digit number. One key observation is that of course if
$$
0 \leq q_{m-1} \leq b - 1
$$
then $q_{m-1}$ represent the most significant digit of the division

Later the problem is stated as

> Let $u = (u_nu_{n-1} \ldots u_1 u_0)_b$ and $v = (v_{n-1} \ldots v_1
> v_0)_b$ be nonnegative integers in radix-$b$ notation, where $u/v <
> b$. Find an algorithm to determine $q = \left\lfloor u/v
> \right\rfloor$.

From this point I have a problem (which is the object of my question). After the observation made that the condition $u/v < b$ is equivalent $(u_n \ldots u_1) < (v_{n-1} \ldots v_0)$ I would also observe that  $v_{n-1}$ is not necessaraly 0. It is later defined the quantity
$$
\hat{q} = \min \left( \left\lfloor \frac{u_n b + u_{n-1}}{v_{n-1}} \right\rfloor,b-1\right)
$$
Where is not actually stated any condition on $v_{n-1}$, which at least shouldn't be $0$. Then the author proves both theorems $A$ and $B$ which they make perfectly sense to me if $v_{n-1} \neq 0$.

One could argue that before the theorems it is said

> ...as long as $v_{n-1}$ is reasonably large...

However I think that this statement should be interpreted more like "we now show how much large $v_{n-1}$ has to be in order to..." So there's actually no assumption here, he wants to show that.

The question is...
Shouldn't basically the condition $v_{n-1} \neq 0$ be clearly stated?
I'm sure there's something subtle about the condition $u/v < b$ that I'm missing...

(I have other questions but I'll go through that later)

Answer (score 1):

Theorem B on page no. 272 of the book states that,

> if $v_{n-1}$ $\geqslant$ $\lfloor b/2 \rfloor$, then q ∈ [ q̂ - 2 , q̂ ].

Therefore, the algorithm is valid only when $v_{n-1}$ $\geqslant$ $\lfloor b/2 \rfloor$, which makes $v_{n-1} \neq 0$ obvious. To ensure this we need to multiply both u and v by a factor ${(= (base-1) / v_{n-1})}$.